# How to prevent redirect to my server from cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to move static resources of my project to cloudfront. I created distribution on cloudfront and I linked my resources to download from distribution's domain. But when resources are requested from cloudfront, then it returns status code 301 and request is redirected to my server. How to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a bit off-topic for SO. You may have better results describing what exactly you have done on https://serverfault.com/ (another StackExchange website - StackOverflow is for programming questions) or contacting Amazon support.

Comment: This is not a programming related question.